# android adMob could not find class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

adMob was working fine until I update eclipse to latest version, now when starting, an error is reported, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdRequest. But adMob library is attached to the project!! Thank you.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);               // Emulator
        adRequest.addTestDevice("3xxxxxxxxxx");  

        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "axxxxxxxxxx");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        layout.addView(adView);

        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
```

and proper reference and permissions on manifest

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your .jar files are checked in Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export.

Comment: pufff that's it!! for any reason was unchecked! I appreciate your help, thank you!